# Filtering dictionary in Swift 4 fails in Xcode, but succeeds in Playground

Tags: swift, xcode9-beta, swift4

In a Swift 4 Playground this code:

```
let time = 1234
let description: String? = nil

let keyed: [String : Any?] = [
    "time": time,
    "description": description
    ]

let filtered: [String : String] = keyed
    .filter{ _, value in value != nil }
    .mapValues { value in return String(describing: value!) }

print(keyed)
print(filtered)
```

Produces this output:

```
["description": nil, "time": Optional(1234)]
["time": "1234"]
```

Which is exactly what I want (only key-value pairs where the original value is not `nil`, with the value unwrapped and converted to a string). However in Xcode 9 (beta 3) my build fails with `'filter' is unavailable`. Is this a beta `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` kind of thing, or am I missing something?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same result. In some projects created with Xcode 9 beta 3, your code compiles without problems and generates the output you expect. Something special in your environment?

Comment: Hmm. I can't imagine so. I'm using a totally vanilla installation of Xcode, to the best of knowledge. Thanks for confirming that it compiles at your end. I'll see if I can figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to resolve this a few ways, including rebooting Xcode, clearing `DerivedData` etc., but at the time nothing worked. I came back to the project several days later and found that the same code which had previously failed to build now built without issue (without my having made any relevant changes). So I'm blaming this on a quirk of the Xcode 9 beta. Or perhaps something was just gummed up somewhere and Xcode eventually cleared a cache or something of that nature. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 4):

You are using Swift 3.2 instead of Swift 4.

You can change it under your target's `Build Options` > `Swift Compiler - Language` > `Swift Language Version`

[image]

Excerpt from Foundation's docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2903389-filter?changes=latest_minor

```swift
func filter(_ isIncluded: (Dictionary.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Dictionary.Key : Dictionary.Value]
```

> Xcode 9.0+

Comment: Nope. Definitely using Swift 4. Good thinking though.

Comment: Sure ? Have you tried using that code on a new empty project ? Works fine here, the error you described only appears when the target's swift lang. version is set to 3.2

Comment: 100% sure. But since you brought it back up I just tried pasting the code from above back into the same project it was failing in before and now it builds fine. I'm 100% sure I haven't changed anything else which would make a difference, so I'm going to blame this on some kind of beta quirk. Thanks for taking the time to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today.

My project that was created in Swift 3.x with xCode 8.x. After the upgrade to xCode 9 it was working fine until today when the `'filter is unavailable'` error kicked in.

Setting the Language Version explicitly to Swift 4 didn't solve it. (Neither did cleaning the project, relaunching xCode etc.)

The trick -that worked for me- was to **convert to whole project to Swift 4**.

(I used started with the migration tool at Edit/Convert/To current Swift syntax, which wasn't too helpful in may case but that's a completely different matter.)

After that the error was gone...