# Bizarre Swift Error: 'filter' is unavailable

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I working on the exercises provided by exercise.io.  One of them is Raindrops, where provided a number, pass "Pling", "Plang", "Plong", or the number depending on if 3, 5, or 7 are factors of the number.

I've already got a simple working solution, but I wanted to iterate over the problem and try different things.  The following example works in a Swift playground, but mysteriously fails with "'filter' is unavailable" in the exercise project.

```
class Raindrops {
    let number:   Int
    let notes:  [ Int: String ] =  [ 3: "Pling"
                                   , 5: "Plang"
                                   , 7: "Plong" ]

    init( _ number: Int ) {
        self.number = number
    }

    var sounds: String {
        return notes.filter{ number % $0.key == 0 }  // (!) 'filter' is unavailable
                   .keys.sorted().map{ notes[ $0 ]! }
                       .joined( separator: "" )
    }
}
```

In the project, the class is called by functions such as this.  (Edited because previous test would have failed as written yet.)

```
func test105() {
    XCTAssertEqual("PlingPlangPlong", Raindrops(105).sounds)
}
```

In my Swift playground, where this error does NOT occur, I have this.

```
class Raindrops {
    let number:   Int
    let notes:  [ Int: String ] =  [ 3: "Pling"
                                   , 5: "Plang"
                                   , 7: "Plong" ]

    init( _ number: Int ) {
        self.number = number
    }

    var sounds: String {
        return notes.filter{ number % $0.key == 0 }
                   .keys.sorted().map{ notes[ $0 ]! }
                       .joined( separator: "" )
    }
}

print( Raindrops( 105 ).sounds ) // Returns "PlingPlangPlong as expected
```

I am using Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235).

I apparently do not have enough reputation to post screenshots.

Comment: Really, I got to get better at this...  Link to the screenshot gallery: https://postimg.org/gallery/31edffcpo/

Comment: Did you try to clean the project? 'Product -> Clean' and also Clean Build Folder -> Select Product with alt key pressed -> then clean build folder

Comment: I have copied your code into an Xcode 9 project and it compiled without problems.

Comment: It fails in the IBM Swift Sandbox: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59da47bd6d31b65a148f61da

Comment: I figured it out via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104619/filtering-dictionary-in-swift-4-fails-in-xcode-but-succeeds-in-playground.  Marked my question as a duplicate.  Basically, the exercism project is provided in a lower version of Swift than 4.0.

Comment: Yup...  Commented out the offending line, converted the project to Swift 4, and now it works.  Appreciate everyone who looked.  I wonder if IBM Swift Sandbox uses Swift 3.x...  I play in there at work since we don't have MacBooks and Xcode there.  :D

Comment: IBM Swift Sandbox is using Swift 4.0 (when selected).  Other 4.0 features are working such as `print(dict["ghi", default: 88])` so something fishy is up.